# A truly puzzling generating function.

Tags: generating-functions

[image]
Would anyone have any idea on how this is done? Truly puzzled at this point :P

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: It's a practice problem assigned by my university professor.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

- $a_0 = 2$
- $a_1 = 2\sqrt2 = 2 \dfrac{\sqrt2}{1}$
- $a_2 = \sqrt2(\sqrt2-1) = 2 \dfrac{\sqrt2(\sqrt2-1)}{1 \cdot 2}$
- $a_3 = \dfrac13\sqrt2(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2-2) = 2 \dfrac{\sqrt2(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2-2)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}$

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
a_n = 2\dbinom{\sqrt 2}{n} \\
f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2\dbinom{\sqrt 2}{n} x^n \\
f(x) = \displaystyle 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{\sqrt 2}{n} x^n \\
f(x) = \displaystyle 2 (1+x)^{\sqrt2} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Many thanks good sir.